# Do we need to set up Roles if we don't care about record ownership?

Tags: permissions, sharing-rule, roles, public-group, org-wide-defaults

We have set our org up with Org Wide Defaults set to Private on a few objects. We open them up via Profiles and criteria-based Sharing Rules to Public Groups made up of users.

Record ownership means absolutely nothing in our org.

Do we need Roles? Is there any reason we would want them? Is there some other functionality we are missing here, or is it ok to not have them at all?

Answer (score 1):

As long as nobody has any roles at all, there's no problem. There's some weird behaviors that occur with some reports if some people have roles and others don't, but aside from that, there's little consequence to not using roles at all.

Comment: Thank you. I ran into this because OWD=Private on Relationships and a user with CRU perms on his Profile cannot see existing Relationships. I removed all Roles because I've been meaning to, and in case they were interfering, but no change. How do I allow the Profile to have CRU on this and other objects or do I have to create individual Sharing Rules for each object?

Comment: @sna You would have to share each object without a Master-Detail relationship, yes. Roles would give you some automatic sharing. You miss out on several benefits by not using Roles, but there's not much of any inherent disadvantage; it might simply make some things more challenging to configure.

Answer (score 0):

Sfdcfox is right, and this answer adds another consideration:

Another consideration / use-case for Roles may be for sharing Report Folders, Dashboard Folders, Email Folders, and List Views with a given Role, and/or role+subordinate roles. This is true with Legacy Folder Sharing and Enhanced Folder Sharing.

Btw, in case its helpful to anyone, another consideration for using Roles is that within your owd settings many objects have a “grant access via hierarchies” boolean setting that would be a mechanism for opening/sharing record access according to the role hierarchy and owner. I know you mentioned ownership having little meaning in your org, but sometimes that checkbox goes unseen so im calling it out here.